# Matching a value on sheet 1 to a value on sheet 2 if cells match.

Tags: excel

I have 2 sheets, sheet 1 is Export Worksheet, sheet 2 is Vista Bom.

Part numbers and descriptions on each. I'm trying to get, if the part numbers in column A of sheet 1 matches the part numbers in column F of sheet 2 then the description in column C of sheet one will match the description in column I of sheet 2.

I feel like it's a simple index or lookup formula but I can't get it. Any help?

Comment: What do you mean: `"then the description in column C of sheet one will match the description in column I of sheet 2"`. Do you need to bring in the data from sheet 1 to sheet 2? can you provide a small sample of existing sheets and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try this in column c of sheet 1 (Export Worksheet):

`=INDEX('Vista Bom'!I:I,MATCH(A:A,'Vista Bom'!F:F,0))`

To handle not found errors:

`=IFERROR(INDEX('Vista Bom'!I:I,MATCH(A:A,'Vista Bom'!F:F,0)),"Not Found")`

Comment: That worked. I had the beginning =INDEX('VISTA BOM'!I:I, MATCH messed up. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you, if this was to correct answer, please mark it with the check by the voting buttons.